# Error on Clojure (unbound fn)

Tags: clojure

Im starting to learn Clojure from the scratch and im stucked on my function. Im trying to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. THis is what i did.

```
(defn suma [x sum]
     (cond
       (= (/ x 3) 0)(let [sum (+ sum x)])
       (= (/ x 5) 0)(let [sum (+ sum x)])))   

(defn main[]
  (def sum 0)
  (def x 3)
  (while(< x 1001)
    (do
      (suma sum x)
      (let [x (+ x 1)]))
  (str "Total = " sum)))
```

I tried several things, but i cant figure out what's wrong....
Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Fixed, the problem was on the `let`, it was not updating the value of the data. Here the solution:

```
(defn suma [x sum]
     (cond 
     (zero? (mod x 3))(alter-var-root #'sum (constantly (+ sum x)))
     (zero? (mod x 5))(alter-var-root #'sum (constantly (+ sum x)))))

(defn main[]
  (def sum 0)
  (def x 3)
  (while(< x 1001)
    (do
      (suma x sum)
      (alter-var-root #'x inc)))
      (str "TOTAL = " sum))
```

Comment: `def` is used for defining vars, not local bindings which are declared using `let`. Your `while` expression will never terminate since `sum` is not mutable. You appear to be treating clojure as an imperative language which is possible but not idomatic.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, already corrected (the one on while).

Comment: The abuse of `def` is certainly, as yet, uncorrected.

Comment: corrected the def's and the while, there's still something missing....

Comment: (apply + (concat  (range 0 1000 5) (range 0 1000 3)) )

Comment: @AssenKolov You need to weed out duplicates.

Comment: Oops, I need a `set` in front of `concat`

Comment: @AssenKolov `(apply set ... )`, I think. I used `distinct`, which is probably slightly slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline using a more functional style. Of course, there is more than one way to do it (TM).   :)

```
> lein repl

user=> (def data (range 20))
user=> data
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)

user=> (defn is-mul-3? [x] (zero? (mod x 3)))
user=> (mapv is-mul-3? data)
[true false false true false false true false false true false false true false false true false false true false]

user=> (defn is-mul-5? [x] (zero? (mod x 5)))
user=> (mapv is-mul-5? data)
[true false false false false true false false false false true false false false false true false false false false]

user=> (defn is-mul-3-or-5? [x] (or (is-mul-3? x) (is-mul-5? x)))
user=> (mapv is-mul-3-or-5? data)
[true false false true false true true false false true true false true false false true false false true false]

user=> (def only-3s-and-5s (filterv is-mul-3-or-5? data))
user=> only-3s-and-5s
[0 3 5 6 9 10 12 15 18]

user=> (apply + only-3s-and-5s)
78
```

### Update:

Here is a more imperitive version.  Clojure values (like in `let` are usually immutable).  You must use an `atom` if you want something like a
mutable Java variable:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn is-mul-3? [x] 
  (zero? (mod x 3)))

(defn is-mul-5? [x] 
  (zero? (mod x 5)))

(defn is-mul-3-or-5? [x] 
  (or (is-mul-3? x) 
      (is-mul-5? x)))

(defn sum-3s-and-5s [limit]
  (let [cum-sum (atom 0) ]
    (doseq [curr-val (range limit)]
      (if (is-mul-3-or-5? curr-val)
        (swap! cum-sum + curr-val)))
    @cum-sum ))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "cumsum = " (sum-3s-and-5s 20))
)
```

with result:

```
~/clj > lein run
cumsum =  78
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The (zero?) operator helped me a  bit, but im not looking to other way of doing the exercise. I would like to do it the way is above. Im having problems now updating the values of the variables, "let" doesnt seem to help....

Comment: Thanks again, i fixed it with `alter-var-root`. I will try it out with `atom`   now. Thanks, i´ll check your answer as good  since it´s the only one.

Comment: It is quite an abuse of `alter-var-root` to use if as an accumulator. It will really confuse anyone reading the code.  :(

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using the sequence library is

```
(->> (concat
      (range 0 1000 3)
      (range 0 1000 5))
     distinct
     (apply +))
```

If you want to do it in an iterative style, Don't use `while`, which depends on side effects. Use `loop` and `recur`, which effect a primitive form of recursion called *tail recursion*:

```
(defn divides? [i j]
  (zero? (mod j i)))

(loop [answer 0, n 0]
  (if (< n 1000)
    (recur
     (if (or (divides? 3 n) (divides? 5 n))
       (+ answer n)
       answer)
     (inc n))
    answer))
```

Both the above produce the same answer.